# How to create a question in Google Forms that allows two sub questions?

Tags: google-forms

I have a question like this
[image]

How can I create a question that contains two sub questions in Google Forms?
The person answering each question must complete two sub questions in each question.Since each question is randomly given to tester, so the two sub questions cannot be separated.

What's the best way to make this work in Google Forms? Or should I use any Google Forms extensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a several ways to do this.

1. Use a title item for the question and questions items for the subquestions.
2. Use a section for each question and questions items for the subquestions.

[image: Google Form items toolbar]